# loop in object using oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

The code below as an object call MY_TYPE and is used to loop into to perform an update.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OTTWEB.MY_PROCEDURE (
    MY_ARRAY IN MY_TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..MY_ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
        UPDATE BULKSMSDETAILS SET STATUS = MY_ARRAY(i).STATUS, REMARKS = MY_ARRAY(i).REMARKS WHERE ID = MY_ARRAY(i).ID;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Unbale to compile the above sp.
Error Message:
PLS-00302: component 'COUNT' must be declared

Below is the Object

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OTTWEB.MY_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
 ID VARCHAR2(1000),
 STATUS NUMBER,
 REMARKS VARCHAR2(1000)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full example.

Type(s) first:

```
SQL> create or replace type t_myt_row as object
  2    (id      number,
  3     status  varchar2(1),
  4     remark  varchar2(10)
  5    );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type my_type is table of t_myt_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table bulksmsdetails as
  2    select 1 id, 'A' status, 'Rem 1' remark from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'B', 'Rem 2' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'A', 'Rem 3' from dual;

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure my_procedure
  2    (my_array in my_type)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Count = ' || my_array.count);
  6
  7    for i in 1 .. my_array.count loop
  8      update bulksmsdetails set
  9        status = my_array(i).status,
 10        remark = my_array(i).remark
 11      where id = my_array(i).id;
 12      dbms_output.put_line('ID = ' || my_array(i).id ||', updated ' ||sql%rowcount ||' row(s)');
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab my_type := my_type();
  3  begin
  4    l_tab.extend;
  5    l_tab(1) := t_myt_row(1, 'X', 'Rem X');
  6    l_tab.extend;
  7    l_tab(2) := t_myt_row(2, 'Y', 'Rem Y');
  8
  9    my_procedure(l_tab);
 10  end;
 11  /
Count = 2
ID = 1, updated 1 row(s)
ID = 2, updated 1 row(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from bulksmsdetails;

        ID S REMAR
---------- - -----
         1 X Rem X
         2 Y Rem Y
         3 A Rem 3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to LOOP, e.g. you can use MERGE

```
create or replace procedure my_procedure(my_array in my_type)
is
begin
    merge into t_myt tgt
    using (select * from table(my_array)) src
    on (src.id =  tgt.id)
    when matched then
        update set status = src.status,
        remark = src.remark
    ;
end;
```

Comment: good approach mate !