# Invalid parameter binding - Object Type stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

To create the object this following url was used.

[loop in object using oracle pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75974738/loop-in-object-using-oracle-pl-sql/75974794#75974794)

Here is the code :

```
public bool UpdateNumberInBulk_(DataTable dataTable)
{
        try
        {
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "MY_PROCEDURE";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    // Create the OracleParameter for the table parameter
                    OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "MY_ARRAY";
                    parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
                    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    parameter.UdtTypeName = "my_type_t";
                    parameter.Value = dataTable;
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                    // Execute the stored procedure
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When the code is executed the following exception is thrown:

> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetUDTDataInBytes(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection,
> OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTNamedType, object, out byte[], out object)
> OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleParameterImpl.SetUDTDataInBytes(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection,
> OracleInternal.UDT.Types.UDTNamedType, object)
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_UDT(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection)
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl,
> OracleInternal.Common.ColumnDescribeInfo, ref bool, int, out
> OracleInternal.Common.ColumnDescribeInfo, out object, bool,
> OracleInternal.Common.SqlStatementType)

Comment: What driver are you using in the connection string?  Check Oracle Error logs for more info : https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/mysql-database/doc/viewing-error-log.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core @jdweng

Comment: Oracle is very sensitive to Oracle Version and Driver Version.  They need to be compatible.  You are getting a binding error which I suspect is a version issue.   Make sure you have everything installed properly according to following including versions : https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html?force_isolation=true